# WebDAV: What is the default file size limit for Windows 7?

Tags: windows, webdav

We have an application at work that mounts a virtual drive using WebDAV. In the past we had to manually set the following values to work around the defaults used by previous versions of the Windows WebDAV client as discussed in [KB 900900](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/900900).

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters\FileSizeLimitInBytes
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters\FileAttributesLimitInBytes

Does anyone know for sure whether the defaults are any higher in Windows 7? Is this workaround still needed?

Comment: The default value is 50000000 in Windows 7.  You need to alter the value for transferring file bigger than it.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind posting that as an answer rather than a comment?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is still true under `Windows 7 Service pack 1` and will also impact services such as online storage mounted as a windows drive.

As stated in the support article [KB900900](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/900900),

> "*This issue occurs because a security change that was introduced in
>   Windows XP SP2 affects the Web Distributed Authoring and Versioning
>   (WebDAV) redirector. This security change makes sure that an
>   unauthorized server cannot force a client computer into a denial of
>   service attack. If you try to download a file that is larger than
>   50000000 bytes, the client computer interprets this download as a
>   denial of service attack. Therefore, the download process stops.*"

Should you wish to workaround the limitation (re: increasing the limit via regedit as stated in the question), detailed instructions are available at the support article.

Comment: You are right for Windows 7, but are you sure about SP1 ? In the "Applies To" section at the end, W7SP1 is not there (but other Windows version and service packs are).

Comment: Well, the limit is set to 50 Mb on my Windows 8.1 machine. :)

Answer (score 1):

The defaults are still 50 MByte on my Windows 10.